# is HDC handle valid for another process?

Tags: c, winapi, c++builder

i am creating clipped HDC (Device Context) handle using windows api, then sending it to another process. Will be this handle valid for drawing in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to expose a method of drawing onto the DC from within your application.

The most likely candidates are Windows Messages defined by you (WM_APP or WM_USER).

```
WM_USER + 1,
WM_USER + 2,
WM_USER + 3,
etc...
```

then you would handle those in your applications WNDPROC

```
switch case
{
  WM_USER + 1:
   // draw a circle
  WM_USER + 2:
   // draw a rectangle
  WM_USER + 3:
   // draw a snowman
}
```

finally from a third party application, they would simple send messages to your application via the SendMessage API:

```
SendMessage(hWndSergey, WM_USER + 1, 0, 0);
```

where the LPARAM and WPARAM can be pointers to global shared memory to exchange parameters or simply dword values etc...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks Bill, but what is faster: named pipes or windows messages?

Comment: @Sergey: faster to develop or faster to send? Named Pipes allow sending between desktops and come with security (DACLs etc), while window messages don't. However, window messages also have their limitations on Windows 7 because of the integrity level of processes ...

Answer (score 3):

A Device Context handle is not going to be valid in another process.  Consider exposing an interface that the other process can use to draw in your window.

Comment: Yes, that is what i need, but how do you accomplish this can you please descriebe?

Comment: @Sergey: that was not actually part of your question. So you should edit it in if that's what you want. The reply by jdigital was spot on, though, given your question.